# unable to delete record with php and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm just trying to delete a record by its row id from a table using php and ajax but when I click on the button it neither shows error nor performs the action.

here is my delete.php code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'db.php';

if(isset($_GET['name'])){
$user = $_GET['name'];

$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$user'") or die (mysqli_error());

$result = mysqli_num_rows($query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

$_SESSION['user'] = $row['username'];
}
}

$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM pm WHERE touser = '".$_SESSION['user']."' ORDER BY pmdate DESC" ) or die (mysqli_error());
$result = mysqli_num_rows($query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
$id = $row['id'];

$delquery = mysqli_query($con, "DELETE * FROM pm WHERE id ='$id'") or die (mysqli_error());
$delresult = mysqli_num_rows($delquery);

}
?>
```

and here is the ajax and delete code of html

```
<a href="home.php?name='.$_SESSION['user'].'-delid='.$id.'" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="delete"></a>

<script>
$("#delete").click(function() {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "delete.php",
success: function(response){                    
$("#messages").html(response); 
}
});
});
</script>
<div id="messages"></div>
```

any one have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Change you query

-> your `"DELETE * FROM pm WHERE id ='$id'"`

-> correct `"DELETE FROM pm WHERE id ='$id'"`

You send POST method true AJAX and in php code you write GET, change it.

Answer (score 0):

You have few issues in your code.
1. you are not sending any parameters to the delete.php page. Please send the record ID to the delete.php page
2. remove * from DELETE query
3. you are adding PHP variables in HTML anchor tag without using PHP tags. you need to correct the link
4. you need to add event.preventDefault() inside your function

Answer (score 0):

you set -> type: "POST" and use a GET method in your link
you  then use -> $user = $_GET['name'];
+ did you try to echo GET / POST vars *before* you query and echo your query ?
+ I guess you send nothing to your page...
+ don't use * in DELETE query